# Adding a native module in React Native 0.71 causes crash, with error code `EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2`

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-native-module, react-native-macos

I recently upgraded my React Native project to 0.71 (I used 0.68 before)
And now my project crashes immediately after some native modules are invoked, and Xcode says:
`com.facebook.react.JavaScript (7): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x(every time changes))`

Yes, the line is red. but if I continue by Ctrl+Cmd+Y, it changes to green but still stuck in same line.
Strangely, which line does stuck changes sometimes, even does stuck on comments.

[image]

I didn't suffered this situation when I used 0.68 or before.
If I delete native module which causes crash and re-`pod install`, problem is gone.

Note that more than one module package are crashing, so I couldn't blame module author.
The only common thing of crashing modules are native modules.